# Canvas in bootstrap 'thumbnail'

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, canvas, image-resizing

I am trying to fit a canvas element inside a 'thumbnails' class div (From bootstrap). Inside this canvas I want to draw an image and then draw something over it. The problem is, with my solution, the Image inside the canvas doesn't behave 'naturally' like it does when I use the img tag. This images illustrate what I'm trying to say:

Normal Image:

[image]

Canvas Image:

[image]

Here's the code I used for each one.

Normal:

```
<li class="span3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="Images/pasta1.jpg" data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="">
       <h3>PASTA 1</h3>
       <p>Pasta a la xxx, con salsa de yyy en zzz.</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

Canvas:

```
<li class="span3">
<div class="thumbnail">
    <canvas id="canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></canvas>
    <h3>PASTA 1</h3>
    <p>Pasta a la xxx, con salsa de yyy en zzz.</p>
    </div>
</li>

<script>
function drawImageTime(canvas_id,image_src,percent)
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById(canvas_id);
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var image = new Image();

    image.onload = function()
    {
        context.drawImage(image,0,0,image.width,image.height,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 200, 100, 0.33)";
        context.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width*(percent/100),canvas.height);
    };
    image.src = image_src;
}

drawImageTime('canvas','Images/pasta1.jpg',73);     
</script>
```

I tried giving the same style of images to canvas elements, but that didn't work. Also manually resizing the canvas element didn't work. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally have the solution to my problem, except for 1 thing I simply can't figure out. I leave canvas placeholders inside each bootstrap 'thumbnail' and I have these functions.

- Draw image and 'loading bar' in a canvas placeholder

  ```
  function drawImageTime(canvas_id,image_src,percent)
      {
          var canvas = document.getElementById(canvas_id);
          var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
          var image = new Image();

          image.onload = function()
          {
              canvas.width = $('#'+canvas_id).parent().width();
              canvas.height = $('#'+canvas_id).parent().width()*(image.height/image.width);
              context.drawImage(image,0,0,image.width,image.height,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
              context.fillStyle = "rgba(75, 100, 200, 0.33)";
              context.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width*(percent/100),canvas.height);
          };
          image.src = image_src;
      }
  ```
- Even out the heights of all thumbnails

  ```
  function equalHeight(group) {
          tallest = 0;
          group.each(function() {
              thisHeight = $(this).height();
              if(thisHeight > tallest) {
                  tallest = thisHeight;
                  console.log("Tallest = " + tallest);
                  //alert(1);
              }
          });
          group.each(function() { $(this).height(tallest); });
      }
  ```

I'm calling the equalHeight function on `$(document).ready`, but it doesn't resize the thumbnails. However if I add an alert() into the code (I have it commented out in the code I posted), it works perfectly.

I don't get it! Any ideas?